# Is it possible for photo's to be uploaded to a form?

Tags: form

I would like to create a form for competition entries. However, there needs to be the option for entrants to upload pictures with their entry form, is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Sure, see documentation on uploading files from front-end form here - https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Oli's comment](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33407/is-it-possible-for-photos-to-be-uploaded-to-a-form#comment40766_33407), there's an example of how to do this in the documentation: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms